# How do I autosuspend a usb device?

Tags: usb, powertop

I am trying to follow the instructions on [Lesswatts](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/devices-power-management/usb.php), to enable **usb autosuspend**.
When I run `powertop`, it says, that I have a device (USB device  2-6 : 2.4G Multimedia Wireless Kit (Chicony)) that is running 100% of the time.

I don't use the wifi and indeed I've blacklisted the wifi driver, so I am pretty confident I don't need this device. So I set the idle timeout to 2 seconds and

> echo auto > `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-6/power/level`

works, but the device is still active. If I try

> echo suspend > `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-6/power/level`

then the bash prompt skips ten lines and stops, but the contents of the file is still **auto**

Comment: The information on Lesswatts is a bit outdated: dmesg says "power/level is deprecated; use power/control instead" and we can't write "suspend" anymore, only "on" or "auto" (see http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt). I'm also searching for an answer to your question, because my USB ports are still powered when the PC is off, and I want to turn them off.

Comment: A "Multimedia Wireless Kit" doesn't have anything to do with wifi -- it sounds more like some kind of a remote control, or a mini wireless keyboard.

Comment: @daithib8 Did Dustin's answer solve your problem? Can you mark as answer if so to let me know I should award the bounty? Thanks.

Comment: @Marius you are right. it was a keyboard and Power top does recommends auto suspend for non-input devices. doh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to echo '**1**' into each of a number of sys files as root.

You can do so like this:

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend; do
  echo 1 | sudo tee $i
done
```

The number '1' means 'auto suspend after '1' second.  You might use '2' here, if that's the behavior you want.

Alternatively, you can install and run the `powernap` utility, which installs a script at `/etc/pm/power.d/usb_autosuspend` that handles this for you automatically.

Comment: Do you know anything about which values mean what? I seem to have 2 in *all* my "files"

Comment: 1 means device suspend within 1 sec, 2 means suspend after 2 secs, etc. -1 means that your device will not suspend.